# How do I parse xml with a namespace using gokogiri (libxml2)?

Tags: xml, go, libxml2

I am using [`github.com/moovweb/gokogiri`](https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri) to parse an XML document. The following works when parsing `var b` but when I try the same on `var a` (which has a namespace) I get no output. How do I parse XML that has a namespace using `gokogiri`?

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/moovweb/gokogiri"
    "github.com/moovweb/gokogiri/xpath"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)
    doc, _ := gokogiri.ParseXml([]byte(a))
    defer doc.Free()
    doc.SetNamespace("", "http://example.com/this")
    x := xpath.Compile(".//NodeA/NodeB")
    groups, err := doc.Search(x)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    for i, group := range groups {
        log.Println(i, group)
    }
}

var a = `<?xml version="1.0" ?><NodeA xmlns="http://example.com/this"><NodeB>thisthat</NodeB></NodeA>`
var b = `<?xml version="1.0" ?><NodeA><NodeB>thisthat</NodeB></NodeA>`
```

EDIT #1:
I've also tried `doc.RegisterNamespace` but got

> doc.RegisterNamespace undefined (type *xml.XmlDocument has no field or method RegisterNamespace)"

and `x.RegisterNamespace` getting

> x.RegisterNamespace undefined (type *xpath.Expression has no field or method RegisterNamespace)"

Comment: Take a look at func (xpath *XPath) RegisterNamespace(prefix, href string), probably before your queries you RegisterNamespace("NodeA", "http://example.com/this") and magic happens?

Comment: @user918176: can't seem to figure it out...doc.RegisterNamespace and x.RegisterNamespace both return errors

Comment: @user918176: I've also tried SetNameSpace("NodeA","example.com/this") and that doesn't work either...empty slice...(eg...NodeA isn't the prefix)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though the namespace used in the XML is assigned no prefix (i.e. is default), you do need to register one and use it in your xpath expression.

This prefix can be anything you like, here I used `ns`. Note it can be different from the prefix used in the document (if any) - the important part that needs to match is the namespace string itself.

---

#### Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/moovweb/gokogiri"
    "github.com/moovweb/gokogiri/xpath"
)

func main() {
    doc, _ := gokogiri.ParseXml([]byte(a))
    defer doc.Free()
    xp := doc.DocXPathCtx()
    xp.RegisterNamespace("ns", "http://example.com/this")
    x := xpath.Compile("/ns:NodeA/ns:NodeB")
    groups, err := doc.Search(x)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for i, group := range groups {
        fmt.Println(i, group.Content())
    }
}

var a = `<?xml version="1.0" ?><NodeA xmlns="http://example.com/this"><NodeB>thisthat</NodeB></NodeA>`
```

---

#### Output:

```
0 thisthat
```